# Make Text Overlap to 1px horizontal line

Tags: html, css, text, browser, compatibility

I am trying to put my text on the horizontal line.
I want if the text length increases the line should get adjusted according to the text length. which is working fine on IE7,8, Mozilla. I want to make it work for Google Chrome.

It's working fine except Google Chrome.
Here is my code:

```
/*CSS*/
.pageHD{ font-size:30px; color:#369; font-weight:bold; padding:20px 0} .pageHD p{display:block; margin-right:10px}
.title-line{ height:1px; border:0 none; background:#e5e5e5; position: relative; right:0; top:0px} 
<!--HTML-->  
<div class="pageHD"><p class="left">Zones Showcases</p> <hr class="title-line" /></div>
```

Can anybody help me for this.
Thanks.!

Comment: Hmmmm.. `<hr>` elements always span the whole width of their containers, also, your positioning rules aren't doing anything, so you can remove those. I don't understand what you are trying to do... have the `<hr>` be only as long as the text? In that case put a `border-bottom` on `.pageHD p`

Comment: I'm on Firefox, and your line is NOT the same length as your text.  I don't quite understand what you are trying to do either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I understand on your question:

You want to make a text overlap a hr element.

If I'm not mistaken on understanding your question, then this would be my answer.

Just make a content after the hr so it would overlap the hr.

Your new HTML would be:

```
<div class="pageHD"><hr class="title-line" /></div>
```

And your new CSS would be:

```
.pageHD {
    font-size:30px;
    color:#369;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px 0
}
.pageHD p {
    display:block;
    margin-right:10px
}
.title-line{
    height:1px;
    border:0 none;
    background:#e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
    right:0;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.title-line:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: 'Zone Showcases';
    bottom: -15px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle Example: [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qYYuT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem

```
border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kR73/1/)

Comment: Is it my browser's fault or it just don't work on Google Chrome?

The text don't overlap the hr in the jsFiddle example.